# Proof to Theorem 3 in 'A modern treatment of the 15 puzzle' by Archer

Tags: permutations, puzzle

I'm reading '[A modern treatment of the 15 puzzle](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15859-f01/www/notes/15-puzzle.pdf)' by Archer and cannot understand the proof to Theorem 3 and how they compute the permutation equation with their examples.

My main problem is this computation with regards to the proof: Note that for any permutation $x$ we have $x^{-1}(a_1,\cdots,a_k) x = (a_1x,\cdots,a_kx)$. Thus, $(1,2,\cdots,7)^{-n}(3,4,5)(1,2,...,7)^n$ yields $(1,2,3),\cdots,(5,6,7)$; $(5,6,...,11)^{-n} (7,8,9)(5,6,...,11)^n$ yields $(5,6,7),\cdots,(9,10,11)$ and $(9,10,...,15)^{-n}(11,12,13)(9,10,...,15)^n$ yields $(9,10,11),\cdots,(13,14,15)$

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15859-f01/www/notes/15-puzzle.pdf     page 797 is the theorem 3

Comment: My main problem is this computation with regards to the proof:   Note that for any permutation x we have x inverse*(a1,...,ak)*x = (a1x,...,akx). 
Thus, 
(1,2,...,7)^-n*(3,4,5)*(1,2,...,7)^n yields (1,2,3),...,(5,6,7);
(5,6,...,11)^-n* (7,8,9)*(5,6,...,11)^n yields (5,6,7),...,(9,10,11) and 
(9,10,...,15)^-n*(11,12,13)*(9,10,...,15)^n yields (9,10,11),...,(13,14,15)